# Do I need public key to deploy applicationn in Gitlab on deployment server

Tags: authentication, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-deployment, ssh-keys, private-key

Question. In A GitLab Ci/CD pipeline. Do i need a public key to deploy my application from github to my deployment  server. Becuase i followed a tutorial from tech with nana (Ci/CD pipline minute 54) in which the author only used a private key in gitlab but I just dont know how she did it

I think ubuntu might need to be configure differenty so that an private key is sufficant when authenticating becuase right now when I follow the tutorial steps and only use my private ket it prompts an error message saying that the public key was not found